# Cannot read property 'outlets' of null

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have next problem : `Cannot read property 'outlets' of null`. My project works, but after some time it stopped working, but i didn't change my code. Help me please.
**Update**
My component with router-outlet:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: '
    <nav-menu></nav-menu>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <footer-component></footer-component>

',
})
export class AppComponent  {}
```

app.module:

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy, APP_BASE_HREF } from       '@angular/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
//+components
@NgModule({
    imports:
    [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent },
            { path: '2016/:link', component: BlogArticleFullComponent },
            {
                path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, 
                children: [
                    { path: 'new', component: NewArticleComponent },
                    { path: 'new-writer', component: NewWriterComponent },
                    { path: 'new-tag', component: NewTagComponent }
                ] },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}
        ])
    ],
    declarations:
    [//components
    ],
    bootstrap:
    [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers:
    [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy }
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

P.S. There is ' quote against ` because stackoverflow ``-is code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There is no way anybody can diagnose the problem with this information.

Comment: Show us some code... part where you call `outlets`

Comment: which code do you want to see? Error happened in  
1) core.umd.js:2838
2) core.umd.js:2843
3) core.umd.js:2844
4) Subscriber.ts:241

Comment: I never wrote `outlets` myself

Comment: You most probably have a <router-outlet> somewhere linked to that issue...
show us some router call with app.module, could be somewhere to start

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue since upgrading from 2.2.4 to 2.3.0... No idea why.

Comment: I had the issue in unit test of component that uses ngrx selector. I had to override the selector with MockStore with appropriate data to fix the issue.

Answer (score 135):

For future reference: I got this error when using `[routerLink]` with an array which looked like `['/foo', null]`. Fixed it by supplying an object instead of `null`.

Comment: I was doing `router.navigate([url])` and `url` was `null`. This answer was a clue for me to go look at the right spot! Thanks arturh, thanks stackoverflow :)

Comment: Yes, almost certainly a data problem for the OP. I just ran into this when a value I was supplying to a router link array was unexpectedly missing. When code breaks without changing the code, look to your data.

Comment: Vote for null support :)
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32614

Comment: In my case, I actually constructed an object and set the id property to null. Solved it by setting id to a string.
Other info here https://newbedev.com/cannot-read-property-outlets-of-null-in-angular-4

Answer (score 11):

Most times this has nothing to do with your route configuration but happens when you try to pass in a dynamic data as a parameter to the route for instance.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user', user?.id]" />user profile</a>
```

The user.id is dynamic and at the point where the page is initialized, the user object might be `null` hence the error.

A quick fix to this will be to add an ng-if to the link, this will force the link to initialize only when the user object is available.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user', user?.id]" *ngIf="user" />user profile</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

This sometimes happens when you auto generate routerLink and this attribute is added `routerLinkActive="router-link-active"` removing it  will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to do a null check first ie. row?.driverId

`<a [routerLink]="['/admin/driver/view', row?.driverId]">{{value}}</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem even with null check operator:

```html
                <a
                    [routerLink]="[
                        '/page/',
                        organizationSettings?.organisation_name_slug
                    ]"
                    >
```

Solved it by adding *ngIf to the element:

```html
                <a
                    *ngIf="organizationSettings"
                    [routerLink]="[
                        '/page/',
                        organizationSettings.organisation_name_slug
                    ]"
                    >
```

Comment: Thank you - your solution sorted out this issue for me.