# Angular 4 routerLink "Cannot read property 'outlets' of null"

Tags: angular

I have the simplest routerLink in the universe:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" [routerLink]="['/beers']">Cancel</a>
```

which uses the following route defintion:

```
{ path: 'beers', component: BeersComponent }
```

Suddenly, it now throws this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'outlets' of null

Other identical routerLinks to the `beers` route work on other views. Other similar routerLinks, such as `home`, work on this page.

Even though an error is thrown, the link works when I click it.

Stumped. Any ideas?

[image: Markup error]
[image: Stack trace]

You can see in the screenshot below, the rendered `<a>` looks fine and there is a `router-outlet` on the page.

[image: Rendered markup]

### Edit

`RouterModule.forRoot([...])` is in the imports of my app.module.

Comment: What does the route definition look like in your route file?

Comment: @koque see updated question.

Comment: I Guess issue is in your BeersComponent

Comment: Do you have the router module included in your application's module?

Comment: @A.J I commented out the contents of the Beers class to verify this. No change. Also other components routing to Beers do not have this issue. I think Beers is clear.

Comment: @Igor Yes see edit.

Comment: @JonathanEckman do you have another route in your routes file that might be conflicting? ex. `/beers/:id`

Comment: There is one report of the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286590/cannot-read-property-outlets-of-null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was another routerLink below the one that was highlighted as having an error:

```
<a ng [routerLink]="['/brewery', beer?.brewery?.id]">
    {{beer?.brewery?.name}}
</a>
```

Beer is loaded async so null was being passed as the id param. Easy fix. Very misleading error message from Angular.

Comment: Thanks, yes very misleading message. I found adding `*ngIf="beer"` on the element prevents that initial load attempt while `beer` is not-yet-loaded.

Answer (score -1):

use Outlets in your routerlink

```
[routerLink]="[{outlets: {primary: ['/beers']}}]"
```